# Unwanted scroll appears during ng-enter animation

Tags: css, angularjs, css-animations

I'm animating using ng-enter/ng-leave a section of the page which 
should have a 'slide in' effect when entering the screen.

I've Added [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qce1wd3x/3/) with dumb example just to clear the point.
HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-switch on="color">
      <div class="{{color}} son" ng-switch-when="blue">
      {{color}}
      </div>
      <div class="{{color}} son big" ng-switch-when="red">
          {{color}}
      </div>
      <div class="{{color}} son" ng-switch-when="other">
          {{color}}
      </div>

 </div>
```

and CSS is:

```
.container{
  width:300px;
  height:350px;
  background-color:white;
  border:2px solid black;
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
.son{
  width:300px;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  height:100%
}
.big{
  width:400px;
}
.blue{ background-color:blue;} .red{background-color:red;} 
.other{ background-color:green;}
.son.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all;
    z-index:100;
    right:-300px;
}
.son.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    right:0;
}
.son.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
}
.son.ng-leave.ng-leave-active{
  z-index:10;
    right:-300px;
}
```

The problem is that some of the views may have a bigger width (the red one in my example), so a horizontal scroll is needed. but when adding 'overflow-x:scroll'   **we now see the scroll also during the animation**. (even when switching from 'blue' to 'green' which shouldn't have scrolls)

Is there anything I can do to hide the scroll during animation ?

Or is there another animation which can achieve the same affects without the scroll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution myself..

Just needed to add another div ('intermediate') between the container and it's children. this div still have 100% of the parent, so now the overflow is on him, and not on the container. 
thus when switching children which don't overflow you don't see the scroll..

```
<div class="container" ng-switch on="color">

      <div class="intermediate" ng-switch-when="blue">
        <div class="{{color}} son" >
        {{color}}
        </div>
      </div>
....
```

and CSS:

```
.container{
  width:300px;
  height:350px;
  background-color:white;
  border:2px solid black;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
.intermediate{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qce1wd3x/5/) is the full solution.